# How to output long line with FileHandler?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

For lines that are not too long, `FileHandler` works fine. But if the line is decently long, it doesn't write anything to the log file. For example here is the code that tries to write a line of 50k characters:

```
public class LoggerExample {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggerExample.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler();
        fileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            sb.append("aaaaaaaaaa");
        }
        LOGGER.info(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: If I run this it prints me the 50000 a's to the console... how are you running this?

Comment: I'm running it from Eclipse

Comment: `it doesn't write anything to the log file` Do you mean the console?
Could you post a screenshot?
I think that's a problem with the Eclipse output, because I tried it with IntelliJ and with cmd, both works.

Comment: I mean the log file on disk, since I'm using `FileHandler`

Comment: @Chin I copied your code and run it... but it doesn't generate a log file anywhere

Comment: I think the default location is your home directory, but you can also specify a path directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileHandler` has a limit as described in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html):

> *<handler-name>.limit specifies an approximate maximum amount to write (in bytes) to any one file. If this is zero, then there is no limit. (Defaults to no limit).*

It states the default as being no limit, but the limit is set by the `logging.properties` file found in the used JRE/JDK installation directory. On my system, Java 8 or Java 17, this file contains the line

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
```

setting the limit to 50000.

Possible solutions:

- set the limit in the constructor of `FileHandler`, e.g:

```
new FileHandler("%h/java%u.log", 0, 1);  // using the default file pattern
```

- having a different configuration file (`logging.properties`) with adjusted limit, specified by the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property.